# Can I substitute Molasses for Honey in Baking Recipes?

Tags: substitutions, baking, honey

Can I substitute one for the other in baking recipes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can also substitute 1 cup molasses with 3/4 cup packed brown sugar + 1/4 water, or 1 cup pure maple syrup, or 1 cup dark corn syrup.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can substitute molasses for honey.  They're going to function essentially the same measure for measure since they are both syrups.

Keep in mind however there will be a difference in flavor (not necessarily bad, just different...which would be the case for one honey over another...different tastes).

Comment: And don't forget molasses will impact the color of the resulting baked good!

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is equal in measure but will make whatever your baking sweeter.

Comment: Which one makes it taste sweeter? The question asks about substituting in both directions.